# Refine search angularjs display all results onload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Objective :**

i want to load all the tours onload first time . but i dont want all the checkboxes selected first time .

**HTML code :**

```
<div ng-repeat="style in styles">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="style.selected"> {{style.name}}
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="tour in tours | filter: hasStyle">Name: {{tour.Tourname}} | Styles: {{tour.style}}</div>
```

**Angular JS :**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope){
  $scope.styles = [{"name":"walking"},{"name":"food"},{"name":"culture"}];
  $scope.tours = [{"Tourname":"sky walk","style":"walking "},{"Tourname":"Accra markets","style":"food,walking"}];

  $scope.hasStyle = function(item){
    return $scope.styles.some(function(style){
      if(style.selected && item.style.indexOf(style.name) > -1) {
        return true;
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Here is [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/eeoBxLBkJt8VNyOEyK5x?p=preview)

Comment: What do you mean ? check boxes are not selected first time

Comment: yes i want to skip the filter first time , i mean during onload